# nodejs express v4 Router(): routes vs users

Tags: node.js, express, router

What is the purpose of the separation of routes and users. In practice, when should we use what?

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users  = require('./routes/users');
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is simply an illustration of how you can define a bundle of routes associated with a module and then associate them with a (partial) path. Look at how they are installed later on in the file, as well as the contents of the two required routes files to get a better idea. The general thought would be that you would have several such route/branches defined - consider each route being a self-contained part of a REST API, for example.

Comment: Aha! Illustration is the key word here. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a template. It gives a example how to write routes. I usually delete the user route and change index route to point to index.html

Comment: No doubt I am so naive :)